# Identify which Macros are referenced by buttons/shapes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I am cleaning up an old workbook filled with useless macros. The Workbook is very big, has lots of buttons in it as well, and has no comments in the code. I'm sure some of the macros are being referenced by buttons somewhere, and some are obsolete.

Is there a way I can verify that a macro is referenced in the workbook, as in by buttons or shapes? I'm not talking about references between subroutines, I used ctrl+f to find links between subs/functions already.

All the help I find online is about figuring out which macro a particular button is using. My problem is the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of the shapes and what they call pretty easily-

```
Sub listem()
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print s.Name & ", " & s.OnAction
Next
End Sub
```

Then you can take a list of all of your functions and do a match, but I don't think it's possible to ask the code to tell you its application.caller unless you trigger it with the caller.

Comment: That's fine, I'll just print the list on a notepad in alphabetical order and refer to it as I read the code to see if it's used. Thanks Ray!